# ninja compile gives an error in Winodws10 MSVS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, v8, ninja

```
C:\Users\UAL\Desktop\New folder\New folder\v8>ninja -C out.gn/x64.release
ninja: Entering directory `out.gn/x64.release'
[1/9] LINK cctest.exe cctest.exe.pdb
FAILED: cctest.exe cctest.exe.pdb
ninja -t msvc -e environment.x64 -- ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/lld-link.exe /nologo /OUT:./cctest.exe /PDB:./cctest.exe.pdb @./cctest.exe.rsp
lld-link: error: <root>: undefined symbol: mainCRTStartup
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I have also set the environment variables as:

```
DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0
GYP_MSVS_VERSION =2015
```

I am just trying to build the hello world application with the steps provided [here](https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-build-v8-on-windows-and-not-go-mad-6347c69aacd4)